# Gruntjs copy subdirectories

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

I'm not sure on the right Gruntjs command for `grunt-contrib-copy`.

Initially, I had a directory with fonts in it and I needed to copy them all from the `app/styles/fonts` directory into a `build/fonts` directory so I used this:

```
{expand: true, flatten: true, src: ['app/styles/fonts/*'], dest: 'build/fonts'}
```

and it worked well.

I've now added a couple of sub-directories (inside `app/styles/fonts`) with more font files in them but when I run the command it will copy the files and the folders but put the contents of the new directories into the `build/fonts`. I want them to remain in their respective folders.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Does `app/styles/fonts/**/*.*` work?

Comment: Could the "flatten" be the problem here ?

Comment: If I don't use flatten then it puts the whole app/styles/fonts directory into the build/fonts directory

Comment: I need to copy the contents and maintain folder structure within `app/styles/fonts`

Comment: What happens if you do `{src: ['app/styles/fonts/**/*'], dest: 'build/fonts'}`

Answer (score 0):

```
{
 expand: true,
 flatten: true, //use only if you want to copy all files in destination folder without their respective folders
 src: ['app/styles/fonts/**'],
 dest: 'build/fonts'
}
```

try this it will copy all files and directories of fonts. but if you use faltten:true then it will copy all files into build/fonts and will break the directory structure.

So for keeping the same structure don't use flatten option.